# Why is putchar() writing a new line in this simple code?

Tags: c, putchar

I do not understand why excessive white space is being written to stdout when I run this program.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    argv++;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(*argv); j++)
        {
            putchar(*(*(argv + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
(base) benjamin@benjamin-G5-5587:~$ ./uecho hello world baby yoyoyo                           
hello                                                                                         
world                                                                                         
baby                                                                                          
         //whitespace?                                                                                     
yoyoy
```

Comment: what's more I do not understand why the last character of 'yoyoyo' is not written!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner loop condition is wrong, causing you to read out of bounds. It's always limited by `strlen(*argv)`, the first argument (thanks to the earlier `argv++`), even when processing the second and subsequent arguments. Since you read out to the length of `"hello"`, you overread `"baby"`, and fail to read all of `"yoyoyo"`. Overreading `baby` by one character ends up writing a `NUL` to `stdout`, which I'm guessing your terminal is interpreting in a manner similar to a newline.

I'd suggest:

1. Fixing the problem so you use the length of each argument to print it, and
2. Replacing hard to understand pointer arithmetic with simple array indexing syntax

End result would look like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)  // Adjust bounds to loop over provided args without mucking with argv directly
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)  // Loop to length of current arg
        {
            putchar(argv[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm curious if you have any insight on whether there is any advantage to learning pointer arithmetic, over the more readable bracket notation?

Comment: @BenJenney: It's useful to *learn* it as part of developing a grounding in how computers actually implement higher level constructs. But it's of relatively little benefit to actually *use* it in real code. In older compilers with poor optimizers, it could potentially improve performance; in modern compilers with optimization turned on, they can do the transformation themselves almost all the time, and in some cases I've seen, achieve better performance when they have the logical context indexing with a common variable provides that arithmetic on separate pointers does not.

Comment: I think I've had one real use case for pointer arithmetic where it actually provided some benefit, and even then it was dubious (just a cheap hack to improve cache locality by allocating a single contiguous block of memory that represented discontiguous data, with pointer arithmetic being used to compute the base pointers for each logical contiguous block). I used a similar trick in reverse to `mmap` a bunch of (page-multiple length) files back-to-back into contiguous addresses (so 1000 files looked like one big array), which was convenient for the use case in question.

Comment: In both cases, it was clever, and fun to write (and the `mmap` case actually simplified the code significantly while improving start up time by avoiding eager slurping of the files), but the actual performance benefit was minimal.